# What do you do with the vodka from your ferm locks?

Tags: airlock

I would've thought the answer was obvious, seeing as how it's alcohol.  But I took a whiff, and it smells like fermentation.  Now I like fermentation, it means beer is on its way.  I don't like fermentation flavored vodka.

First, is there some reason why drinking this would actually be bad?  Can't imagine alcohol being bad for you, just curious.

Second, any ideas on what to mix it with?  I know I can experiment, but if it doesn't work, I'll be committing alcohol abuse, and that's going to ruin my brew day.

I know this might sound on the edge of homebrew question, talking about vodka, but I believe this is a semi-common byproduct of the brewing process.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd mix it with everything else going down my drain that day.

Comment: Agreed.  I can't imagine why you'd want to drink it.

Comment: Yeah, if the thought of waste is a concern I think you need to find cheaper vodka.

Comment: @theracoonbrew-  Or an AA meeting.

Comment: Indeed, if it doesn't smell/taste good to you, then why on earth would you want to consume it?

Comment: I think you guys are too long out of college.  I'm also too old to be thinking (or drinking) like a college student.

Answer (score 4):

Save it for your next brew day and mix it with a glass of your first runnings (assuming you're brewing all-grain).   This is also awesome with spiced rum, bourbon, scotch whisky, or probably just about any other good spirit.

Comment: (note:  I've never actually done this with airlock-vodka...  i use star-san in mine)

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to drink an amount equal to what I put in the fermentation lock so the feeling of alcohol abuse is only 'half-bad'.